# Revolutionary war pensions

Tags: united-states, legal-history, military, governmental-liability

In Volume 1 of the statutes at large, it mentions the revolutionary war pensions. Most of these were never paid, and due to judgment interest if the law was enforced today the damages would be in the trillions of dollars.

Is the federal government liable to pay revolutionary war pensions?

Answer (score 4):

Everyone who might have been entitled to revolutionary war pensions is dead, and the statute of limitations to bring suit to collect unpaid revolutionary war pensions expired as to their survivors and estates more than a century ago. The last U.S. Revolutionary War pension payment was paid [in 1906](https://blog.genealogybank.com/last-revolutionary-war-widow-receives-final-pension-in-1906.html).

By comparison, the last Union Civil War widows *almost* all died in the mid-20th century (in cases of young women who married aging civil war veterans), although the very last two Civil War pension payment was made [in the year 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irene_Triplett) when the recipients died at ages 90 and 101 respectively. The Civil ended about 70 years after the Revolutionary War ended.

Revolutionary war pension information is now [mostly relevant as a source of genealogical information](https://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2015/summer/rev-war-pensions.html) about one's ancestors.

Comment: At first I couldn’t figure this out. So that would be a 15 year old born 1850 taking part in the civil war in 1865, in 1935 aged 85 he married a 16 year old and in 2020 she is 101 years old. Correction: It was a daughter born in 1930.